# Grabbing number from selected class based on string match

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, string-matching

I need to grab the number between `[` and `]` within the selected class of an `li` list, and store the number in a variable. I've tried the following, but I'm missing something. I'm not sure of the `regex` required to look between brackets and grab a string.

Javascript

```
var assetID = $(".selected:contains('on-air-date').find('[]');
```

HTML

```
<ul id="asset-list" class="expandable selectable normal" style="height: 671px;">
    <li class="selected">
        <div class="thumb">
            <a href="/content/assets/750">
                <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
            <div>
                <strong>Title of story</strong>
                <br>
                <span class="on-air-date">
                    On air: 10/28/14 05:30:00pm
                    [750]
                </span>
                <br>
                <span class="blue radius label">Staging</span>
                <span class="green radius label">Live</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="thumb">
            <a href="/content/assets/4200">
                <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
            </a>

        </div>
        <div class="title">
            <div>
                <strong>Another story title</strong>
                <br>
                <span class="on-air-date">
                    On air: 12/10/14 02:09:18pm
                    [4200]
                </span>
                <br>
                <span class="blue radius label">type label</span>

            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <div class="thumb">
            <a href="/content/assets/4201">
                <img src="https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
            </a>
        </div>
        <div class="title">
            <div>
                <strong>Yet another story title</strong>
                <br>
                <span class="on-air-date">
                    On air: 12/10/14 02:09:18pm
                    [4201]
                </span>
                <br>
                <span class="blue radius label">type label</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

JSFiddle: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/mattography/k3keq3vL/)

Comment: Could you please fix the javascript errors in your code. Currently it rather does not work at all instead of working incorrectly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression can help you get the number as follows:

```
var num = $('.selected span.on-air-date').text().replace(/[^\[]*\[(\d+)\].*/,'$1');
```

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/k3keq3vL/7/)

Answer (score 3):

Your current code is invalid, as `:contains` is used to look for a text value within an element, not a class. You need to use `find()` and `text()` to retrieve the value in the element. From there you can use a regular expression to extract the value in the braces. Try this:

```
var selectedAirDateText = $('.selected').find('.on-air-date').text();
var matches = /\[(.+)\]/gi.exec(selectedAirDateText);
console.log(matches[1]); // = '750'
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/k3keq3vL/3/)

Answer (score 1):

`:contains('on-air-date')` not valid, you cannot use `contains` to access the child elements with the specified class. Also `.find('[]')` not valid. The following code worked for me:

```
  $('.selected').click(function () {
     var assetID = $(this).find('.on-air-date').text().split('[')[1].replace(']', '');
     //this first splits the text into two by '['
     //then we get the second half by [1]
     //finally we remove the last character ']' by using .replace

     alert(assetID);
  })
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/k3keq3vL/1/

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to first get the single item you need or run an $.each to get all in the page.

```
//run the each statement
$(".on-air-date").each(function(index,value) {

     //set the string (str) variable to the value's text which is inside the <span>  
     var str = $(value).text();

     // match the string with [ ] with anything inside. and then remove the last ].  Then take the substring of the content after the [
     var value = str.match(/\[(.*?)\]/g)[0].replace(/\]/g,'').substring(1,str.length-1));

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/k3keq3vL/8/
Open your console to see the list of numbers returned in the console.log of the string match and substring